# Akka parent is not getting messages from its child

Tags: java, akka

I fail to send messages from a child actor to its parent.
I'm using Java 8 & Akka 2.5.1

The master parent is created in an impl class:

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("My-Akka");
ActorRef master = system.actorOf(Props.create(Master.class));
master.tell(new Object_B_Message(), ActorRef.noSender());
```

The master class have the following receive implementation:

```
public Receive createReceive() {
   return receiveBuilder()
       .match(Object_B_Message.class, message -> {
                    ActorRef objectB= context().actorOf(Props.create(ObjectB.class));
                    objectB.tell(message, this.getSelf());
   })
        .match(Object_C_message.class, message -> {                      
                    ActorRef objectC = context().actorOf(Props.create(ObjectC.class));
                    objectC.tell(message, this.getSelf());
  })
```

I now want ObjectB to accept the message, do something and activate ObjectC by sending an object_C_message to the master.

I'm able to activate object B, but when it tryies to send the object_c_message it just seems to go nowhere and the master is not receiving it.

Here is the code in ObjectB:

```
public Receive createReceive() {
 return receiveBuilder()
   .match(Object_B_message.class, message -> {
```

And none of the following lines of code was able to send the message to the master:

```
ActorRef ref = getContext().parent();
this.getSelf().tell(object_c_message, this.getSelf());
ref.tell(object_c_message, getSender());
ref.tell(object_c_message, ActorRef.noSender());
ref.tell(object_c_message, this.getSender());
ref.tell(object_c_message, ref);
ref.tell(object_c_message, context().parent());
ref.tell(object_c_message, this.getSelf());
```

Akka prints to the console the following message 10 times before terminating the application:

```
[akka://My-Akka/user/$a/$f] Message [object_c_message] from Actor[akka://My-Akka/user/$a/$f#-489049040] to Actor[akka://My-Akka/user/$a/$f#-489049040] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off...'.
```

BTW - just to make sure the code is wired up correctly I was able to direcly call the master with object_C_message and the master got the message and activated Object C.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your lines.

First of all, you don't show how you are creating `object_c_message` . I assume you are doing the right thing.

```
ActorRef ref = getContext().parent();
```

So far, so good. Although, you could just user `getSender()` .

1. `this.getSelf().tell(object_c_message, this.getSelf());`
   This is wrong. You are sending the message to yourself.
2. `ref.tell(object_c_message, getSender());` This is half wrong. You are sending the message to the parent *on behalf of the current sender* (who is also your parent).
3. `ref.tell(object_c_message, ActorRef.noSender());` Again, half wrong. It will send it to your parent, but the parent won't be able to respond.
4. `ref.tell(object_c_message, this.getSender());` This is duplicated of 1.
5. `ref.tell(object_c_message, ref);` This is equivalent to 4. since ref == getSender() in this scenario.
6. `ref.tell(object_c_message, context().parent());` This is equivalent to 2. since ref == getSender() in this scenario.
7. `ref.tell(object_c_message, this.getSelf());` We got it! This is the right one you could use. Alternatively, `getSendert().tell(object_c_message, getSelf());` would also do.

So why is it not working? Who knows. Try adding more logging statements, debugging withing your ide while inspecting the values of getSender() and getSelf() and ref. Maybe you are not creating the right object and it goes to unhandled/dead letters in the receive of the master.

One more thing you can do, is at creation time to NAME your actors, so your logs will say what actor is sending / receiving the deadletters messages, instead of akka generated intelligible names ( `context.actorOf(DemoActor.props(42), "name");`

Do these things, and post the updated logs with names. We'll be able to help you out more.

Comment: Hi @Diego Martinoia. Thanks for the tips. I added the names to the Actors and tried running in debug mode in the ide. 
One strange things is the console message that I get:
`[CoordinatedShutdown(akka://My-Akka)] Starting coordinated shutdown from JVM shutdown hook`

I have a feeling that somehow my master is shutting down right after it sends the messages to its children, so when they are trying to call the master it is not available anymore.

Comment: @t-rex-50 More likely, your "main" is terminating, and the JVM terminates, and the Asystem with it. Post your main code.